# How to make the sun lamp not the HDR cast shadow in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I have an object that's lit by an HDR and a sun lamp. I want that object to cast shadow by the light coming from sun lamp only. How to do that?

Comment: I think that if you are using an image to *lighten* the object, necessarily you'll get shadows too. You can dampen their strenght, soften the contrast between light and dark areas, make the shadows border smoother, but not avoid them completetly. What would the scene look like without the sun lamp in your opinion? Could you specify a little bit your question?

Answer (score 4):

Starting with a scene like this where one layer has a cube and a sphere are being lit by HDRI only.

The sphere has the shadows disabled in the cycles settings

[image]

On a separate layer containing the plane, a copy of the sphere with the shadows enabled and a sun light.

Create two render layers, one that uses the environment, and a second one that does not, and has the shadow pass enabled:

[image]

[image]

Combine the shadows on the compositor.
[image]

[image]