# Restrict hdri from casting shadows

Tags: lighting, shadows, hdri

Is there any way to stop the hdri from casting shadows ? I only want the reflection/light.

Comment: Basically do the opposite of [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38851/cycles-how-do-i-exclude-the-environment-texture-from-reflections)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43667/how-to-make-the-sun-lamp-not-the-hdr-cast-shadow-in-cycles/43674#43674

Comment: Im sorry what do you mean by "Opposite" can you clarify ?

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using render layers or compositing ?